# In Google analytics, how do I see the paths through my site that users took to get to a page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, users

On my site I'm currently trying to work out the typical paths that users follow within my site in order to get to an end result of a certain page.

I have discovered how to use landing page- to see where users go once they start on a certain page. However what I am looking for is kind of the opposite- how users navigate to that particular page in the first place.

just looking at the behaviour flow normally doesn't really work as I have a huge site and this page is just one amongst many. I would like to filter out everything else and look exclusively at the flow to page X.

Is there anything like this available somewhere in GA?

Comment: You can set up goals with the landing page being the end goal and then you'll be able to view the funnel visualisation (this may require setting up some other URL's that the user might likely proceed via en-route to the goal though) - worth playing around with perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data calculation could be complex and you are already aware of Behavior flow which is the best way to do comparative analysis.

However, try these alternatives:

Set up goal to a particular URL and funnel it down. (recommended, if you have to track any specific channel)

OR

1. Create a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) for a particular *Page Depth* filter (say 3)
   and the target *Page* (say xyz.htm).
2. Add *dimension level 1* as **landing page**, *dimension level 2* as **next page path**, *dimension level 3* as **page**.
3. Use a preferred metric to compare data (say Unique pageviews).
4. Identify the % of pages from different sections of the website.

Note: Reports might be very different for different sessions and date ranges. For accurate results, it is highly recommended to do such analysis for one particular session at a time.

Comment: goals seem to be the way.
Seems odd to use them in this way since some of the particular pages i am looking for are error pages but it works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Content Drilldown` feature, as described in http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2340779/google-analytics-content-reports-understanding-the-key-benefits

See the **Navigation Summary** section and *Entrances/Previous pages* with *Exits/Next pages* in this report.

Comment: Can you explain more about how content drilldown works here in this answer?   While a link is helpful, it is better to summarize it here.  Its better not to force users to click and the linked page may break or disappear.